# iPhone Google Maps app open from iOS App, only shows coordinates not location name.

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, nsstring, uiapplication

In my iOS app, I'm opening google map app from inside the code. I can open it but when it launches, I can only see the coordinate of the location. Does it make any sense to anyone ?
It must be location name or coordinate with location name.
Anybody know how to display name ?

I am using this code:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"comgooglemaps://maps.google.com/?q=%f,%f", lat, lng];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: u need which name area name or address, or what u need

Comment: u need city, state, or country, or which name u want to display

Comment: Yes exactly, i want Google Maps app to display the Name of location as well. As you said - city, street

Comment: get a screen shot and make ur question clear

Comment: Hi, Thanx for replying guys, see the attached image it might clear the doubts.
http://postimg.org/image/p2kgcr3vf/

Answer (score 0):

use this below function for getting address for lat long..

```
-(NSString *)getAddressFromLat:(NSString *)Lati Long:(NSString *)Longi {

NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%@,%@&sensor=true",Lati,Longi];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
NSError *e = nil;
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
return [[[json valueForKey:@"results"]  objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];

}
```

pass this function below code:

```
  NSString *strAdd =[self getAddressFromLat:LATITUDE Long:LONGITUDE];
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?q=%@&center=%@,%@&views=satellite,traffic&zoom=15",[strAdd stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"],LATITUDE,LONGITUDE]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```

Above this code great work for me. try this . this will work great..